# Azure Ad B2c - Login with token

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am using msal-browser.js library to perform a login/ registration in to azure ad b2c.

Is there a way to trigger a silent login using a bearer token?

I receive a token with a request to a website and I want to pass this token into azure ad so that the user is automatically loggedin. Token must be validated by azure ad.
Not sure how to handle this, is this even possible?

Tried to use msal.acquireTokenSilent function from msal instance but this is not working if user it not logged in..

```
const bearerToken = 'MY_VALID_TOKEN';

 $msal.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: scopes,
            validateAuthority: true,
            authenticationToken: bearerToken,
        }).then(function (response) {
            // Validation was successful, you can now use the access token
            console.log("Access token: " + response.accessToken);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

This causes an error.

Any help is highly appreciated.